# Angular 13 is not working with node version 16.17.0

Tags: node.js, angular, node-gyp, node-sass

My angular application was **working fine** for node version `14.15.0`.

I upgrade my node version to `16.17.0` and deleted the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`.

Now I'm trying to do `npm install` but I'm getting the below error related to `node-gyp`/`node-sass` packages.

[image]

Comment: it seems to be `node-gyp`/`node-sass` problem, my suggestion would be try `rimraf rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm install`

Comment: @PankajParkar still the same errors after deleting the node_modules then `npm cache clean --force && npm install`.

Comment: Can you please give try with [github thread](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809)?

Comment: @PankajParkar the issue is coming due to `node-sass` since `node-sass` incompatibility with Node 16.

Comment: FYI, `node-sass` is deprecated and may not work "as-is"
 on certain platforms with some combinations of OS and CPU architecture. Dart Sass is a quick replacement and is recommended. [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above issue is coming due to `node-sass` since [lower node-sass version is incompatible with Node 16](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/3077#issuecomment-834282177).

It works fine after upgrading the `node-sass` dependency in the project.

OR

`CXXFLAGS="--std=c++14" npm install` worked for me as well on M14 Mac. [Reference](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38367#issuecomment-902163778)